# JPA - @OneToMany as a Map

Tags: java, jpa, dictionary, one-to-many

This seems like a common enough case, but as JPA newbie, I am having trouble figuring this out. I'm using EclipseLink and PostgreSQL, but this should relate to just the JPA spec.

I have one table `PRIMARY` that has an ID and then a bunch of other columns. There is another table `SECONDARY` that has a foreign key into the `PRIMARY` table also called `ID`. This `SECONDARY` table has a composite key of that `ID` and a varchar representing a locale.

So, in the `Primary` entity I want to have a field of type `Map<String, Secondary>` where the key is the locale string from the `SECONDARY` table and the entry is the `Secondary` entity. My `Secondary` class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Secondary
{
     @Id
     private Long id;
     @Id
     private String locale;
     private String str1;
     private String str2;
     .....
}
```

I'm thinking I want to use the `@MapKeyJoinColumn` annotation, but I can't seem to get the other annotations to work. I tried this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="LOCALE")
private Map<String, Secondary> secondaryByLocale;
```

This resulted in it trying to select a column named secondaryByLocale_key which doesn't exist.

I then tried this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="SECONDARY", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ID"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="LOCALE")
private Map<String, Secondary> secondaryByLocale;
```

This results in the following error:

```
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field secondaryByLocale] from the entity class [class com.foo.Primary] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
```

I tried adding the referencedColumnName to the annotation (I wasn't sure what it even should be), but I got the same error.

As suggested, I tried using `@MapKey` as follows:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
@MapKey(name="LOCALE")
private Map<String, Secondary> secondaryByLocale;
```

This results in the following error:

```
Exception Description: The map key [LOCALE] on the entity class [class com.foo.Secondary] could not be found for the mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.UnidirectionalOneToManyMapping[secondaryByLocale]].
```

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong, and there's a better way to annotate the Map field. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using `@MapKey(name = "locale")` instead.

`@MapKeyJoinColumn` is used when your map key is an entity, but here you're just using the locale String.

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you post the code for your `Secondary` class?

Comment: I've updated the question with the `Secondary` code and the results from trying `@MapKey`

Comment: I've updated my answer - your entity attribute is called "locale" not "LOCALE"...

Comment: Also, are you sure it's valid to have two `@Id` fields on your `Secondary` entity?

Comment: Interesting, I haven't had any problems with case sensitivity before, but that definitely fixes it. Also, the two `@Id` annotations seem to work just fine. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Great :-)  With case sensitivity, you'll have mixed results when you're referring to table column names but here you're referring to a class property (to be used as a Map key) so definitely case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is worked with 
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@MapKeyColumn(name="COLUMN_NAME")

or

You can directly try with only 
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)